# What are the chances of getting a Universala Kongreso ticket at the venue?

Tags: culture, movado, universala-kongreso, events

When I go to https://uea.org/kongresoj and in the "ALIĜADO" box click the ["Reta aliĝilo"](https://uea.org/kongresoj/alighilo) link, I get to a page saying

> Pardonpeton! La reta aliĝado por la UK estas finita.
>
> Vi povas aliĝi al la UK surloke en la kongresejo ĉe giĉeto "Surlokaj Aliĝoj".

The downloadable PDF form for printing and registration by snail mail (link ["Elŝutebla aliĝilo"](https://uea.org/pdf/uk2019/alighilo_lahtio.pdf) in the same box) also mentions

> La CO en Roterdamo akceptas aliĝilojn ĝis la 15-a de junio 2019. Post tiam, oni aliĝu surloke dum la UK.

How good are my chances of getting a congress ticket at the ticket office there?

I'm living in Switzerland and wouldn't want to book flight and hotel and plan the trip (and go on the trip) to Finland if there's a great risk I won't be able to attend the congress because the tickets are sold-out or something.

Comment: They are selling one-day tickets at la kongresejo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chances are 100%. The *Reta aliĝilo* is just saying that in Rotterdam they have closed the books for Congress registrations. They are busy with compiling the *Kongresa libro* with the program details and the names of the participants. They are no more able to help with accommodation, excursions, etc.

Just book your flight and hotel. You will be warmly accepted at the *Kongresejo*. Welcome to Finland!

Comment: Surely there is some maximum number of participants that are permitted. Do you know what the maximum is? And do you know how many people have signed up thus far? That's what the chances are going to depend on. It's not like they can accept an arbitrarily large number of people, right?

Comment: @Joffysloffy I wish we had that kind of problem. The several events, parallel gatherings, unorchestrated collection of people pose no real problem. Theoretically the opening ceremony could be a bit overfilled.

Comment: @JoopEggen Okay, I see. I thought it'd be kind of a waste to plan for many more people to come than signed up beforehand, but I suppose just some more events might be full(er), while there still being plenty of room for other things.

Comment: UEA says there are, at the moment, 854 registered participants. This means the 104th UK  will be one of the small congresses. In the last 10 years the number of participants has varied between 706 and 2689. The last UK in Finland (Tampere, 1995) had 2443 participants. The _Kongresejo_ is a sports hall with more than 3000 seats for the opening ceremony and othe mass meetings.

Comment: Mi aliĝis surloke, do tio respondo evidente pravas!